# solving ordinary coupled differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, singularity, finite-difference-method

I have a set of 8 ordinary differential equations containing matrices which I need to solve using  initial conditions. I have written the equations in this form:

```
 s1 = NDSolve[{ 
   D[nuI[[1]], 
     t] == -((\[Omega]*m2).nu[[1]] - 
        nu[[1]].(\[Omega]*m2)) + \[Mu]*((nu[[1]] + nu[[2]]).nu[[1]] - 
        nu[[1]].(nu[[1]] + nu[[2]]) - (nuI[[1]] + nuI[[2]]).nuI[[1]] +
         nuI[[1]].(nuI[[1]] + nuI[[2]])) + \[Mu]b*((-nub[[1]] - 
           nub[[2]]).nu[[1]] + 
        nu[[1]].(nub[[1]] + nub[[2]]) + (nubI[[1]] + 
           nubI[[2]]).nuI[[1]] - nuI[[1]].(nubI[[1]] + nubI[[2]])),
   
   D[nuI[[2]], 
     t] == -((\[Omega]2*m2).nu[[2]] - 
        nu[[2]].(\[Omega]2*m2)) + \[Mu]*((nu[[1]] + nu[[2]]).nu[[2]] -
         nu[[2]].(nu[[1]] + nu[[2]]) - (nuI[[1]] + 
           nuI[[2]]).nuI[[2]] + 
        nuI[[2]].(nuI[[1]] + nuI[[2]])) + \[Mu]b*((-nub[[1]] - 
           nub[[2]]).nu[[2]] + 
        nu[[2]].(nub[[1]] + nub[[2]]) + (nubI[[1]] + 
           nubI[[2]]).nuI[[2]] - nuI[[2]].(nubI[[1]] + nubI[[2]])),
   
    D[nu[[1]], 
     t] == ((\[Omega]*m2).nuI[[1]] - 
       nuI[[1]].(\[Omega]*
          m2)) + \[Mu]*((nuI[[1]] + nuI[[2]]).nu[[1]] - 
        nu[[1]].(nuI[[1]] + nuI[[2]]) + (nu[[1]] + nu[[2]]).nuI[[1]] -
         nuI[[1]].(nu[[1]] + nu[[2]])) + \[Mu]b*((-nubI[[1]] - 
           nubI[[2]]).nu[[1]] + 
        nu[[1]].(nubI[[1]] + nubI[[2]]) - (nub[[1]] + 
           nub[[2]]).nuI[[1]] - nuI[[1]].(nub[[1]] + nub[[2]])),
   
    D[nu[[2]], 
     t] == ((\[Omega]2*m2).nuI[[2]] - 
       nuI[[2]].(\[Omega]2*
          m2)) + \[Mu]*((nuI[[1]] + nuI[[2]]).nu[[2]] - 
        nu[[2]].(nuI[[1]] + nuI[[2]]) + (nu[[1]] + nu[[2]]).nuI[[2]] -
         nuI[[2]].(nu[[1]] + nu[[2]])) + \[Mu]b*((-nubI[[1]] - 
           nubI[[2]]).nu[[2]] + 
        nu[[2]].(nubI[[1]] + nubI[[2]]) - (nub[[1]] + 
           nub[[2]]).nuI[[2]] - nuI[[2]].(nub[[1]] + nub[[2]])),
   
   
   D[nubI[[1]], 
     t] == ((\[Omega]*m2).nub[[1]] - 
       nub[[1]].(\[Omega]*m2)) + \[Mu]*((nu[[1]] + nu[[2]]).nub[[1]] -
         nub[[1]].(nu[[1]] + nu[[2]]) - (nuI[[1]] + 
           nuI[[2]]).nubI[[1]] + 
        nubI[[1]].(nuI[[1]] + nuI[[2]])) + \[Mu]b*((-nub[[1]] - 
           nub[[2]]).nub[[1]] + 
        nub[[1]].(nub[[1]] + nub[[2]]) + (nubI[[1]] + 
           nubI[[2]]).nubI[[1]] - nubI[[1]].(nubI[[1]] + nubI[[2]])),
   D[nubI[[2]], 
     t] == ((\[Omega]2*m2).nub[[2]] - 
       nub[[2]].(\[Omega]2*
          m2)) + \[Mu]*((nu[[1]] + nu[[2]]).nub[[2]] - 
        nub[[2]].(nu[[1]] + nu[[2]]) - (nuI[[1]] + 
           nuI[[2]]).nubI[[2]] + 
        nubI[[2]].(nuI[[1]] + nuI[[2]])) + \[Mu]b*((-nub[[1]] - 
           nub[[2]]).nub[[2]] + 
        nub[[2]].(nub[[1]] + nub[[2]]) + (nubI[[1]] + 
           nubI[[2]]).nubI[[2]] - nubI[[2]].(nubI[[1]] + nubI[[2]])),
    D[nub[[1]], 
     t] == -((\[Omega]*m2).nubI[[1]] - 
        nubI[[1]].(\[Omega]*m2)) + \[Mu]*((nuI[[1]] + 
           nuI[[2]]).nub[[1]] - 
        nub[[1]].(nuI[[1]] + nuI[[2]]) + (nu[[1]] + 
           nu[[2]]).nubI[[1]] - 
        nubI[[1]].(nu[[1]] + nu[[2]])) + \[Mu]b*((-nubI[[1]] - 
           nubI[[2]]).nub[[1]] + 
        nub[[1]].(nubI[[1]] + nubI[[2]]) - (nub[[1]] + 
           nub[[2]]).nubI[[1]] - nubI[[1]].(nub[[1]] + nub[[2]])),
    D[nub[[2]], 
     t] == -((\[Omega]2*m2).nubI[[2]] - 
        nubI[[2]].(\[Omega]2*m2)) + \[Mu]*((nuI[[1]] + 
           nuI[[2]]).nub[[2]] - 
        nub[[2]].(nuI[[1]] + nuI[[2]]) + (nu[[1]] + 
           nu[[2]]).nubI[[2]] - 
        nubI[[2]].(nu[[1]] + nu[[2]])) + \[Mu]b*((-nubI[[1]] - 
           nubI[[2]]).nub[[2]] + 
        nub[[2]].(nubI[[1]] + nubI[[2]]) - (nub[[1]] + 
           nub[[2]]).nubI[[2]] - nubI[[2]].(nub[[1]] + nub[[2]])), 
   
   ci, di, ei, fi, c2i, d2i, e2i, f2i}, 
  Flatten[{Variables[nu[[1]]], Variables[nuI[[1]]], 
    Variables[nub[[1]]], Variables[nubI[[1]]], Variables[nu[[2]]], 
    Variables[nuI[[2]]], Variables[nub[[2]]], 
    Variables[nubI[[2]]]}], {t, 5, 10}, Method -> "BDF"]
```

where initial conditions are :

```
\[Theta] = 11.53*\[Pi]/180;
m2 = 1/2*{{Cos[
     2 \[Theta]], -Sin[2 \[Theta]]}, {-Sin[2 \[Theta]], -Cos[
      2 \[Theta]]}}
nu0 = {{1, 0}, {0, 0}};
ci = Thread[Flatten[nu[[1]]] == Flatten[nu0]] /. {t -> 5};
nuI0 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
di = Thread[Flatten[nuI[[1]]] == Flatten[nuI0]] /. {t -> 5};
nub0 = {{1, 0}, {0, 0}};
ei = Thread[Flatten[nub[[1]]] == Flatten[nub0]] /. {t -> 5};
nubI0 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
fi = Thread[Flatten[nubI[[1]]] == Flatten[nubI0]] /. {t -> 5};
nu20 = {{1, 0}, {0, 0}};
c2i = Thread[Flatten[nu[[2]]] == Flatten[nu20]] /. {t -> 5};
nu2I0 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
d2i = Thread[Flatten[nuI[[2]]] == Flatten[nu2I0]] /. {t -> 5};
nu2b0 = {{1, 0}, {0, 0}};
e2i = Thread[Flatten[nub[[2]]] == Flatten[nu2b0]] /. {t -> 5};
nu2bI0 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
f2i = Thread[Flatten[nubI[[2]]] == Flatten[nu2bI0]] /. {t -> 5};


\[Omega] = 1;
\[Omega]2 = 4;
\[Mu] = 10;
\[Mu]b = 10;
```

and the matrices are:

```
nu = Table[
  Array[Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], i], #1, #2][t] &, {2, 2}], {i, 1, 
   3}]
nuI = 
 Table[Array[
   Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho]I, i], #1, #2][t] &, {2, 2}], {i, 1, 
   3}]
nub = 
 Table[Array[
   Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho]b, i], #1, #2][t] &, {2, 2}], {i, 1, 
   3}]
nubI = 
 Table[Array[
   Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho]bI, i], #1, #2][t] &, {2, 2}], {i, 1, 
   3}]
```

I want to solve these equations and finally plot with r. But on solving, NDSolve is showing the following error:

At t == 5.297478985619947`, step size is effectively zero;
singularity or stiff system suspected.

I tried to put higher values of the lower limit but still similar error exists. Also I tried by changing the method of differentiation but no change occurred.
Can you please help with this?

Comment: You mentioned that you tried different methods, did they include `StiffnessSwitching` and/or `IDA`?

Comment: Actually there are 32 Riccati type equations in this system. Why do you think that solution should be stable?

Comment: @debsuvra  Yes I tried these methods also but the result is same.

Comment: Setting , `\[Mu] = 1; \[Mu]b = 0;` allows the computation to run to completion. showing rapid but not explosive exponential growth.  This suggests to me that the ODE system itself is unstable.